# Cheering for a race

Tags: phrase-requests

When it comes to cheering from the spectator's stand for a friend who is participating in a race, where I live has this phrase which means "add oil" if translated directly into English. Thus, for those who don't speak English very well here, they would yell out "add oil" to their friends who are in a race. I would like to know how English speakers actually say it. I have a feeling this would vary between regions and I would appreciate if anyone could suggest a few from each of the US and the UK.

Edit: *Add oil* has now been officially added into the Oxford Dictionary and so this question is not necessary anymore!

Comment: *Go for it*, would be a similar phrase in BrE, but if it were a friend, I would probably go for *'You're doing well!' to give a more positive friendly spin as well

Comment: "Go!", "floor it", "put the peddle to the metal"

Comment: @Mitch, shouldn't that be "pedal to the metal"? As in a gas pedal to the metal floor of the car?

Comment: @rajah9 Or criminy, yes, of course. 'pedal'. I was making puns in my head with with mettle and meddle and puddle and muddle and I only came halfway up for air.

Comment: *Step on it* or *kick it into high gear*, are similar to *pedal to the metal*, maybe a little less motorsport specific as far as exhortations go.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like an **idiom**, which generally don't translate well.

This isn't an expression used in English, in this context.  I think the closest equivalents might be **"get a move on"** (BrEng-specific, I think) or **"get the lead out"** (more AmEng-specific).

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_a_move_on

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_the_lead_out

Having said that, neither of these is particularly **friendly**.  If you just wanted to shout encouragement you could shout **"Come on, `<name>`!"**

Comment: Thanks for your timely response. Would people yell their phrases out from the spectator's stand or they are said to friends in situations like before a game?

Comment: From where does "**pull the lead out**" come? That sounds very strange to my BrE tongue, does it have some sort of gun connotation with the lead?

Comment: @MissJoey These are definitely calling pu from the stand phrases.

Comment: @MissJoey I beg your pardon, it should have been *"get the lead out"* - I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Thank you for providing a link for **"pull the lead out**"

Answer (score 3):

"Let's go!" or "Let's go, `<team name>`!" is what we say in the US to motivate the team.  It is sometimes repeated as a chant.

See: [Etymology of phrase "Let's Go (favorite sports team!)"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97535/etymology-of-phrase-lets-go-favorite-sports-team)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming a lot about the origin of your "add oil" idiom, but I believe in the U.S. the closest idiom matches would either be

- "**[grease the wheels](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grease+the+wheels)**," - loosely meaning to speed something up
  (which would literally apply to an engine; figuratively to a process
  or political situation, *maybe* a race)

or

- "**[light a fire](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/light+a+fire+under+someone)**," or figuratively putting heat under someone to
  make him move (faster).

Comment: *grease the wheels* and *light a fire* don't sound like exhortations during a race to me.