# Which type of phrase is "Let's go, Brandon"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a name for a type of phrase like "Let's go, Brandon"? For some context, [NPR](https://www.npr.org/2021/10/30/1050782613/why-the-lets-go-brandon-chant-turned-meme-can-be-heard-on-the-floor-of-congress):

> In this case, the phrase isn't actually about supporting a guy named Brandon. Instead, it's a euphemism that many people in conservative circles are using in place of saying, "F*** Joe Biden."

More specifically, I am looking for the name for a phrase like this that intentionally hides a seemingly unrelated deeper meaning behind the literal interpretation of a phrase. In this case, the hidden meaning is vulgar.

So far, it seems like it is a euphemism/minced oath. Perhaps this is also a form of irony?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Etymology of phrase "Let's Go <favorite sports team>!"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97535/etymology-of-phrase-lets-go-favorite-sports-team)

Comment: Sounds like a deep question -- but I don't quite follow what you're saying about the linguistically unrelated deeper meaning.

Comment: Wikipedia has a page on this phrase. Among other things, it’s a minced oath.

Comment: Coded. I think that at its point of origin, the phrase was a minced oath, but as it came into use, it became more than that.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate for the term "dog whistle" a la [Southwest Airlines Pilot Under Investigation for Using Dog-Whistle Phrase ‘Let’s Go, Brandon’ During Flight](https://www.diversityinc.com/southwest-airline-pilot-under-investigation-for-using-dog-whistle-phrase-lets-go-brandon-during-flight/)

Comment: Possibly some readers may not be aware of the term; I think for context the OP should quote a few lines from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Go_Brandon to explain it, and hopefully that will be enough to get the question reopened.

Comment: I've edited the post for clarity and to provide more detail.

Comment: *"intentionally hides a seemingly unrelated deeper meaning"* - In this case it's not just *seemingly* unrelated, it really is a completely unrelated meaning, it just has a supposedly similar sound.

Answer (score 3):

Such a phrase may be called a **euphemism**.  For example, you could say, "On Sunday, Senator X was seen wearing a baseball cap displaying the euphemistic political slogan, "Let's go, Brandon."

Google's Oxford Languages quick search for *euphemism* provides:

> a mild or indirect word or expression substituted for one considered to be too harsh or blunt when referring to something unpleasant or embarrassing.
>
> *“downsizing” as a euphemism for cuts*

Comment: euphemism is the actual word used in the OP...? which you edited to add..? what's going on? OP missed that part you mean?

Comment: @BCLC - Sorry, I'm not following. / I added the comma in "Let's go, Brandon." That was my only edit.  You can see my edit by clicking on "edited X mins ago."

Comment: @aparente001 BCLC is pointing out that your suggestion ("euphemism") is already included in the question. I don't think that he/she realizes that it wasn't there when you contributed your answer.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - Thanks, I see that now.

Comment: @BCLC - OP added that one hour after I posted my answer.

Comment: @jsw29  How do you get that it's specifically the speaker who is bothered?  The definition I cited doesn't say that.  Also, my practical experience with this word doesn't match with your definition.  Perhaps you'd like to post a Question?